# What is X-Cc-Webhook-Signature in coinbase webhook api?

Tags: php, laravel, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I want to accept bitcoin payment using the [Coinbase Commerce API](https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/).
I have [created a charge using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967513/how-to-check-coinbase-commerce-apibitcoin-payment-is-complete-or-not). Now I want to create a webhook to verify payment status.

I crate webhook as below (https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-commerce-php/blob/master/examples/Webhook/Webhook.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use CoinbaseCommerce\Webhook;

$secret = 'SECRET_KEY';
$headerName = 'X-Cc-Webhook-Signature';
$headers = getallheaders();
$signraturHeader = isset($headers[$headerName]) ? $headers[$headerName] : null;
$payload = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));

try {
    $event = Webhook::buildEvent($payload, $signraturHeader, $secret);
    http_response_code(200);
    echo sprintf('Successully verified event with id %s and type %s.', $event->id, $event->type);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo 'Error occured. ' . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

I try to call using GET and POST Method. Getting `$payload` and `$signraturHeader` blank.

Comment: they are probably the headers used to send you the hash / certificate so that you can be sure that the request you have received actually comes from them, and not from someone else

Comment: When i test form "Webhook subscriptions(https://commerce.coinbase.com/dashboard/settings)" send test show error-> Failed to establish a connection to the remote server at www.xxx.com @Berto99

Comment: Have you installed the [official PHP library for CoinBase](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-commerce-php#installation)? Checked the error logs?

Comment: _“Failed to establish a connection to the remote server at www.xxx.com”_ sounds like it could not reach your server at all. Are you sure you uploaded this to somewhere where it is publicly available, without any access restrictions?

Comment: Yes @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Yes Dear, @CBroe

Comment: Can you give us a URL to verify that? _“I try to call using GET and POST Method”_ - if you want to test this by making the request yourself, then you would of course need to provide a proper signature value in that header. And using GET makes little sense to begin with, as this tries to read from `php://input`, which takes the data from the request body, which usually only POST request have.

Comment: Does anyone solved this problem?